# Can't update some fields in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an online game and I have a problem with updating some fields in database.
Here's the form and the php code.

```
<form method='post'>
                <div style="float: left; width: 630px; color: white;">
                    <div style="float: left; width: 400px; background: #555; height: 20px;">
                        <?php
                        if ($row['Protected'] == 1)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <img src="images/pass.png"></img>
                            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" style="height: 18px;" />
                            <?php
                        }
                        echo("<input type='submit' name='enter' style='background: #555; text-decoration: underline;' value='$row[Name]' />");
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: right; width: 229px; background: #555; margin-left: 1px; height: 20px;">
                        <?php
                        echo($row['NrPlayers']);
                        echo("/");
                        echo($row['MaxPlayers']);
                        echo(" Players");
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;">
                        <?php
                        echo($row['Descr']);
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background: #ccc; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 2px; color: black;">
                        <?php
                        echo($row['FName']);
                        echo(" ");
                        echo($row['LName']);
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php$row['Id_Room']?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="protect" value="<?php$row['Protected']?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php$row['Pass']?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="nr" value="<?php$row['NrPlayers']?>" />
                </div>
            </form>
<?php
                if (isset($_POST['enter']))
                {
                    if ($_POST['protect'] == 1)
                    {
                        if ($_POST['pass'] == $_POST['password'])
                        {
                            $nr = $_POST['nr'] + 1;
                            mysql_query("upadte users set Id_Room = '$_POST[id]' where Id_User = '$_SESSION[id]'");
                            mysql_query("update rooms set NrPlayers = '$nr' where Id_Room = '$_POST[id]'");
                            header("Location: game.php");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ?>
                            <span style="color: red; text-align: center;">The password you entered is incorrect.</span>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    if (($_POST['protect'] == 0))
                    {*/
                        $nr = $_POST['nr'] + 1;
                        mysql_query("upadte users set Id_Room = '$_POST[id]' where Id_User = '$_SESSION[id]'");
                        mysql_query("update rooms set NrPlayers = '$nr' where Id_Room = '$_POST[id]'");
                        header("Location: game.php");
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

There are two updates and one redirect. So, updates don't work but redirect does.

Comment: "updates don't work" <= please elaborate on that. Do you get any errors? what behaviour do you experience exactly?

Comment: Also you have a typo :) mysql_query("upadte -> mysql_query("update

Comment: there is another typo in: <?php$row['Id_Room']?> it should read <?=$row['Id_Room']?> if you have short-tags enabled.

Comment: and please do never ever use any values from $_GET, $_POST or $_COOKIE directly in your sql queries. everyone could delete your complete database easily. always filter them, make sure the values are valid or simply map them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

Submit the form to a template, then dump out all your values from the form scope to ensure your getting what you need through from the form.

Step 2:

Using some test values write your queries in a query editor like mysql work bench or php myAdmin so that you have working queries.

Step 3:

Write the code that generates your queries in php, but instead of executing it dump it out to screen. Do this until the outpu looks like the query you designed in the step 2.

Step 4:

Finish the page and execute the query, look out for typos, syntax errors and security holes. then dump out results from the query.

Things you need to check in your current code:

```
mysql_query("upadte users set Id_Room = '$_POST[id]' where Id_User = '$_SESSION[id]'");
```

Typos - 'upadte' , inline substition - Id_Room = '{$_POST['id']}'.

Always walk through thorough debugging steps before posting large amounts of code and asking for help.